# Magento 2: Multiple Database Connection

Tags: magento2, database, multiple

I'm using below script to connect for my another database.

https://www.maxpronko.com/blog/new-database-connection-in-magento-2

I stuck after

> Next step is to configure resource model to use new connection. The
>   di.xml configuration file will help to set new resource name to
>   resource model.

Or any better way?

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for the same solution and came across this:

https://blog.hauri.me/magento2-custom-database-connection.html

I didn't implement the resource model part since I don't need it now but the following part helped me a lot.

`/** @var Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $this->resourceConnection **/
$connection = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection('custom');`

I use it my code like this (this is part of controller for test purposes)
in my code to get a custom connection

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resourceConnection
)
{
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
}

public function execute()
{
    $connection = $this->_resourceConnection->getConnection('custom');
    $select = $connection->select()
        ->from(
            ['tt' => 'testtable']
        );
    $data = $connection->fetchAll($select);

    print_r($data);
}
```

All the rest just like in here https://www.maxpronko.com/blog/new-database-connection-in-magento-2

I hope this helps!